# Exception Logging in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am currently having an issue logging exceptions in my PowerShell script. I am trying to copy a file to C:\Windows\System32 and I want to add an error line to my log file if it errors. I have tried this two ways so far.

**Example 1:**

```
$LogPath = "C:\Test.txt
$scriptPath = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition

Copy-Item $scriptPath\Devcon.exe C:\Windows\System32 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable $Errors

Foreach($error in $Errors)
{
    add-content -Path $LogPath -Value $($error.Exception) -Force
}
```

**Example 2:**

```
$LogPath = "C:\Test.txt
$scriptPath = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition

Try{
    Copy-Item $scriptPath\Devcon.exe C:\Windows\System32
}
Catch [System.Exception]
{
    add-content -Path $LogPath -Value "There was an error why trying to copy the file." -Force
    add-content -Path $LogPath -Value $Error -Force
}
```

I can add items to the log file so I know it's not a permissions issue with the file. What am I missing?

Comment: Approach 1 will not work with those variable names.  `$error` is a reserved automatic variable name that stores the global list of errors, you can't use it as a loop variable.  In general, @Neolisk is correct, you need to set `ErrorAction` to `Stop` to force.  If you change your variable names (e.g. `foreach( $err in $errors )`), you might still be able to use overall approach #1, if you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the error you are getting is non-terminating. This is why it does not end up in a catch block.

Try this instead of your Copy-Item line:

```
Copy-Item $scriptPath\Devcon.exe C:\Windows\System32 -ErrorAction Stop
```

[Help on ErrorAction (MSDN)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315352.aspx).